# Table row height ios Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating an application with a Table view controller. I am following this tutorial [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWgr_wNtGPM). Now my problem I want to change the height inside of the items. Each cell has two labels vertically. I set height for the row like this.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if (indexPath == selectedIndexPath ){
            return 200
        }else {
            return 100
        }
    }
```

How can I change the height of items inside of cell.

**Edit 1:**

In default label has only one line of text after clicked there is multiple line of text. So need to change the height of the label and the whole cell.

**Edit 2:**

Before click my cell I have like this. [image]

After I clicked my cell I want like this:
[image]

Comment: Use auto layout, and apply constraints accordingly it'll be expand automatically.

Comment: Please check my edit

Answer (score 1):

Make the items in the call scale dynamically depending on the `bounds` size of the cell.

You can **configure layout constraints** to achieve that. You would set constraints, define margins etc. The label would scale depending on the height.

[image]

Alternatively you can **do the layout manually**, calculating and setting the frames in `layoutSubviews` method of the cell.

Here is a nice tutorial that might help you [Dynamic Table View Cell Height and Auto Layout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout)

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Don't even know how to google it. Will you suggest any tutorial ?

Comment: Sure, I updated my answer with a link to a nice tutorial.

Comment: Could you please take a look at my Edit, and my screenshots.